# Recode string in column based on the name of the column, looked up in another table

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a df containing values for several ids and multiple variables. There is a reserve code, "no", the same code for all variables, that I would like to recode to different values based on another df, reserves.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(~id, ~var1, ~var2, ~var3,
               10, "1.1", "no", "3.45",
               11, "2.3", "4.67", "5.00",
               12, "no", "no", "7.65",
               13, "7.8", "7.8", "no")

reserves <- tribble(~var, ~replacement,
                    "var1", "0.01",
                    "var2", "0.45",
                    "var3", "0.02")
```

I am looking for a tidy solution to this. I know I can do this manually, as in:

```
df$var1[data$var1=="no"] <- reserves$replacement[reserves$var==var1]
...
```

But I would prefer a lookup-style solution that I could pipe into the rest of my workflow. Below is my desired result.

```
df <- tribble(~id, ~var1, ~var2, ~var,
               10, "1.1", "0.45", "3.45",
               11, "2.3", "4.67", "5.00",
               12, "0.01", "0.45", "7.65",
               13, "7.8", "7.8", "0.02")
```

So, replacing the "no" values with values specified in another table. Can I get a hand with this?

Comment: Hi! Your example is not reproducible (check [these instructions please](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example)), and it's also not clear what you need to achieve

Comment: Hi @BastiánOleaHerrera, I have edited my question to something I hope is clearer. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: should the last column be `var3` instead of `var`? You dont have `var` in your `replacement`, but the `NA` is replaced in the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'), names_to = 'var')


df %>% left_join(reserves, by=c('var')) %>% 
  mutate(value=ifelse(value=='no' & !is.na(replacement), replacement, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = var, values_from = value)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id var1  var2  var  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    10 1.1   0.45  3.45 
2    11 2.3   4.67  5.00 
3    12 0.01  0.45  7.65 
4    13 7.8   7.8   no
```

Answer (score 2):

**A tidyverse(dplyr) solution with a simple `mutate(across())`**

We can transform `reserves` into a named vector with `deframe` and use `replace`.
For every(`cur_column()`, use `reseves[cur_column()]` for replacement.
I corrected the typo like @jpsmith suggested.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

reserves <- deframe(reserves)

df |> mutate(across(matches('var\\d+'),
                    \(x) replace(x,
                                 x=='no',
                                 reserves[cur_column()]
                                 )
                    )
             )

# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id var1  var2  var3 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    10 1.1   0.45  3.45 
2    11 2.3   4.67  5.00 
3    12 0.01  0.45  7.65 
4    13 7.8   7.8   0.02
```

Comment: You might want to add `library(tibble)` for `deframe`.

Comment: Does not library(dplyr) load tibble by default?

Comment: Thought too, but it only loads `as_tibble` and `tibble`, but not tibble-library specific methods. Maybe `deframe` and `enframe` are the only ones specific to tibble?

Comment: nice knowing that. Thank you, Andre. I usually load the whole tidyverse, so I am usually not interested in that nitty gritty. I updated the answer

Comment: anyway, this should be addressed by tidyverse maintainers, these should be `dplyr` sub-packages

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ifelse` function to perform something on a column if a certain condition is met, in this case, `var1 == "no"`, then the following argument is what you want to re place the value with (in your case, the reserve data for said variable), and lastly, the value if the condition is not met, i.e, the same value (`var1`):

```
df |> 
  mutate(var1 = ifelse(var1 == "no", reserves |> filter(var == "var1") |> pull(replacement), var1))
```

Following this, we can create a function that does this for any column, not only for `var1`:

```
replace_no <- function(variable) {
  replacement_data <- reserves |> filter(var == rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(variable))) |> pull(replacement)
  
  ifelse(variable == "no", replacement_data, variable)
}
```

The we just use out new function:

```
df |> 
  mutate(var1 = replace_no(var1),
         var2 = replace_no(var2))
```

Returning this:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id var1  var2  var  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    10 1.1   0.01  3.45 
2    11 2.3   4.67  5.00 
3    12 0.01  0.01  7.65 
4    13 7.8   7.8   no
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can use `sapply`:

```
ccols <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

df[ccols] <- sapply(ccols, \(x){
  df[df[,x] == "no", x] <- reserves[reserves$var == x, "replacement"]
  df[,x]
  })
```

Output:

```
#      id var1  var2  var3 
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1    10 1.1   0.45  3.45 
# 2    11 2.3   4.67  5.00 
# 3    12 0.01  0.45  7.65 
# 4    13 7.8   7.8   0.02
```